# Loop on element and extract all child properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, element

I have the attached HTML [HTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y4OelsQ2s3ZOkekA5Wv0cz-0UwnD5Sey/view?usp=sharing)
I would like a javascript code to execute on chrome console that
1 - go on all the below span

[image]

[image]

that have a child go recursively run on child and extract property

the output that i woudl like to have is

```
id="preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionTabF55group13" --> class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" --> data-form-designer-id="" --> "Group 13 Parties"
id="preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10"--> class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" --> data-form-designer-id="" --> "(05) [3/17] Declarant"
id="preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-2" ---> class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all other ui-state-hover" --> data-form-designer-id="F55-10-2" --> role="textbox" --> label="(05 016) [3/17a] Name"
id="preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-3" ---> class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all other ui-state-hover" --> data-form-designer-id="F55-10-3" --->  role="textbox" --> label="(05 017) [3/18] Declarant identification No. "
```

the label is on the span element on the previous object

i have this code

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('preview:section:subSectionF55group13');
let child = myElement.querySelector('[class*="ui-accordion-header"]');
let menuName = ""
let contentName = ""
for (let i = 0; i < myElement.children.length; i++) {
  if (myElement.children[i].className == ('ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top')){
      menuName=myElement.children[i].innerText
      console.log('ui-accordion-header ' + menuName)
  }
  if (myElement.children[i].className == ('ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content')){
      const myContentsElements = document.getElementById(myElement.children[i].id);
      console.log(myContentsElements.children);
      for (let x = 0; x < myContentsElements.children.length; x++) {
        contentName=myContentsElements.children[x].id;
        console.log(myContentsElements.children);
        console.log('ui-accordion-content ' + contentName);
      }
  }
}
```

I am in particular looking for

```
0: {id: 'preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-2', text:'Group 13 Parties', text:(05) [3/17] Declarant, text: '(05 016) [3/17a] Name'} 
1: {id: 'preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-3', text:'Group 13 Parties', text:(05) [3/17] Declarant, text '(05 017) [3/18] Declarant identification No.'}
```

where the id is the id of the input/select near to the label

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you currently have. Please, read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: @mplungjan first line of the code there is a link to download the HTML

Comment: Why not add it to the snippet so I do not have to go elsewhere to stitch YOUR code together? We really want a ***[mcve]*** where the active word is MINIMAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cbdu10zp/

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('preview:section:subSectionF55group13');
let headers = [...myElement.querySelectorAll('[class*="ui-accordion-header"]')].map(elem => elem.textContent);
let labelsAndInput = [...myElement.querySelectorAll('[class*="ui-accordion-content"] *')]
  .filter(elem => elem.tagName === "LABEL" || elem.tagName === "INPUT")
  .filter(elem => elem.id || elem.textContent.trim())
  .map(elem => ({
    type: elem.tagName,
    role: elem.getAttribute('role'),
    dataformdesignerid: elem.getAttribute('data-form-designer-id'),
    id: elem.id,
    text: elem.textContent.trim()
  }));
console.log(labelsAndInput)
const contents = labelsAndInput.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  if (cur.type === "INPUT") {
    const elem = labelsAndInput[i - 1];
    acc[cur.id] = {
      id: elem.id,
      text: elem.text,
      role: cur.role,
      dataformdesignerid: elem.dataformdesignerid,
    }  
  }  
  return acc
}, {});

console.log(headers)
console.log(contents)
```

Comment: @mplungian you are very near 
i need also the element on the last level as the input with his label I have add a screenshot

Comment: See update......

Comment: the elem.id is the id of the label. What you would like to have is the id of the input and the text of the label do you think that is possible?

Comment: Possibly. I’ll look later

Comment: @mplungian to be more precise what i looking for is :
0: {id: 'preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-2', text:'Group 13 Parties', text:(05) [3/17] Declarant, text: '(05 016) [3/17a] Name'}
1: {id: 'preview:section:subSectionF55group13:subSectionF55-10:F55-10-3', text:'Group 13 Parties', text:(05) [3/17] Declarant, text  '(05 017) [3/18] Declarant identification No.'}

where the id is the id of the input/select near to the label

Comment: No trivial. See update

Comment: @mpungian Whoo, one more and next I 1000% done, how I can separate what is from declarant and what is from Representative? in the output are all in the same list, can we had also the label of the header?
i add a screenshot to be more specify

Comment: You can do that yourself, no? Just add an outer loop.

Comment: thnak you for your help i will try it

Comment: @muplungian https://jsfiddle.net/bfgp8xhu/ i have add a few more dailes for the element but seam that i can't print it can you give a tip what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I do not see the change...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9sy2okr/ on this i have added     type: elem.tagName,
    role: elem.role,
    dataformdesignerid: elem.getAttribute('data-form-designer-id'),
    id: elem.id,
    text: elem.textContent.trim()

Comment: You do not save the stuff you map

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cbdu10zp/